# Passport does not redirect after successful auth

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I cannot figure out why `passport` would nod redirect me after a successful auth to my `/dashboard` page. I can see the request in the Network tab of my broswer, but my page does not change, and stays on the current login page.

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
        database.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', username, (error, result, fields) => {
            if(error){
                return done(error);
            }
            if(result[0] == undefined){
                return done(null, false);
            }
            bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, function(err, res) {
                if(!res){return done(null, false);}
            });

            return done(null, result[0]);
        });
    }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.email);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(email, done) {
    database.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? ", email, function(err, result, fields){
        done(err, result[0]);
    });
});

router.post('/login', 
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/dashboard',
                                    failureRedirect: '/' }));

router.get('/login', function(request, response){
    response.render(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views', 'login.pug'));
})

router.get('/', function(request, response){
    response.render(path.resolve(__dirname, 'views', 'register.pug'));
})
```

Could you please help me identifying the problem?

Comment: Was the request finished?

Comment: Yes. I found the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was preventing the default behavior of the button I as using to submit the form, so the page never refreshed, resulting in the web page never updating.